# Can someoene help me find the minimum of an array using functions? My code does'nt work

Tags: c

How can I find the minimum of an array using functions? This is the code I wrote, but whenever I run it it says

> min=2

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int  v[1000];

void read(int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nGive element v[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int minimum(int n,int v[])
{
    int i,min;
    min=v[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(v[i]<min)
        {
            min=v[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

main()
{
    int n,i,min;
    printf("Give n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    read(n);
    minimum(v);
    printf("min=%d",min);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile.

Comment: How can this even compile? `minimum` requires two arguments and you are passing just one.

Comment: I think this can compile. It's C.

Comment: Use prototype-style function definitions - always! `main()` is not.

Comment: It can compile, for that i'm sure.

Comment: Now that you're back, can you respond to anyone who spent time answering your question and let us know whether any of it helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variable `min` in `main()` is not the same as the local variable `min` in `minimum()`.

The `min` in `main()` is uninitialised and hence undefined behaviour (UB). The fact that it consistently returns 2 - for now - is purely happenstance.

So, why did you make `minimum()` return an `int` - but then not actually do anything with that return value?

I'm not going to advise using global variables, for long-since-tired reasons. Rather, in `main()`, simply set its local `min = minimum(n, v)`. Now what do you get?

*son of edit: adding what the others said about you not passing enough arguments to `minimum()`.*

Answer (score 2):

```
int minimum(int n,int v[])
```

You function takes two arguments and in `main` you pass it only `1` parameter -

```
minimum(v);
```

Call like this -

```
min=minimum(n,v);
```

Or directly write like this -

```
printf("min=%d",minimum(n,v));      // no need of min in main
```

***Note*** -

**1.** `main()`  **->** `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc,char *argv[])` .

**2.** Also using global variable is not a good idea and also *no need of it* . Declare `v` in `main` and pass it to functions .

Answer (score 1):

- Give enough arguments to `minimum`.
- Assign the return value of `minimum` to `min` in function `main`,.

Therefore, change `minimum(v);` to `min = minimum(n, v);`

Answer (score -1):

If you want just the function there it is:

```
int minimum(int n, int v[]){
    int min = 10000, i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(min > v[i]) min = v[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

The variable `min` should receive a number that is never going to be reached by one of the values in the array. Because you want to be sure that even the very first number will be lower than the initiated `min` value.

**But here is some tips:** Before posting any questions here in **StackOverFlow** you should look at your code and be sure that it compiles and work. So we can test it before anything. Also be more clear about your problem and come with more information.

Read this after correcting your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: ...why not just set `min` to the 1st value and then iterate from the 2nd number onwards, changing `min` to each successive lower number? hey, the op already got that far, despite the rest, so this is moving backwards. "you want to be sure that even the very first number will be lower than the initiated min value." - i... what?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! It works either way, with the min variable initiated or set to the first value. But what if he called, by mistake, the function with an empty array? And also, what is so obscure on my frase:  "you want to be sure that even the very first number will be lower than the initiated min value.". What didn't you understand from it ? Thank you again, I'll edit my answer if you still found it confusing.

Comment: Ha, really? "It works either way" - only by requiring the function's writer to psychically choose an arbitrarily high value greater than that passed by any given caller. And if the latter called with an empty array, she/he would (A) be doing it wrong, so who cares, and (B) receive a false answer of 10000 - or whatever other magic number you chose. Magic  numbers are a bad idea in most cases, and here, none is needed, so why bother? Don't put this down to me being "confused" when your answer is unnecessarily esoteric, prone to error, and bad advice for an OP who is clearly very new to all this.

Comment: Oh ok! Setting the value to the first number in the array isn't using magic numbers? If the number 10000 is the number returned, which is never reached by any number in the array in my example, wouldn't be safer to just place the a if-else statement? If you declare a variable inside a function with a imaginary number that maybe not there, you'll have much more problems than if you had it declared in the first place! And also, my answer isn't unnecessarily complex. It just answered what he is asking: "How can I find the minimum of an array using functions?"

Comment: No, using an actual relevant runtime value is.... kinda the literal opposite of a magic number. If you want to protect against the caller passing in stupid things, then use `assert` or some other method of 'exception handling'. Or just let them take their own chances; if they want their hand held; they can use a managed language. And finally, the point isn't merely to answer: it's to answer with good advice, which I don't see here. If you want to keep rambling instead of actually responding, OK, but I doubt I'll stay around for it

Comment: You said that he's new to the language, do you really think that using assert to do an exception handling is the easiest way? Can you see what I'm trying to say? You're correcting my answer saying to be more simple and saying that I'm using magic numbers and that is error prone (I agree!), but you are offering me an answer that is almost the same or greater complexity, and I'm just trying to give him an answer without producing other errors ... Here is the two codes, at the bottom is your suggestion: http://codeshare.io/LeuWG . Did you really think that your tip here was easier or safer?

Comment: You'll argue about anything except the actual subject, eh? Clearly my suggestion of `assert` was in reference to your irrelevant objection about the possibility of invalid input, not the OP (who by the way, not that it matters, but I suspect is not a "he"). And what is difficult about using the correct `v[0]` instead of the arbitrary `10000` - especially when the OP _already did the former so wouldn't have to change/learn anything_? I'm not going to continue arguing with these diversions or agree that it's somehow better to 'simplify' answers to the point where they become bad advice. Cheerio.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I wanted to come to a common point, but it seems we're both going to lose time trying to convince each other of its own code conventions, like using if-else or assert. Cheers!

Comment: Using `int min = 10000` is a problem should `v[] = { 12345, 12345}`.  Using `int min = INT_MAX` is more resilient.